# I need a word for "something bad that happened in public"

Tags: synonyms

So I'm writing this letter apologising for my son's behaviour.
What the son did was he pulled his pants down and showed everyone his thing. 
I wrote "I am writing to apologise for his ________ behaviour..."

What word could I put there that would sound sophisticated and make me look good?

Comment: I am writing to apologize for my son's unacceptable behavior...

Comment: [distasteful, improper, inadmissible, objectionable, offensive, repugnant, undesirable, unsatisfactory, disagreeable, obnoxious, unpleasant, unwanted, unwelcome,...](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unacceptable)

Comment: Inappropriate, antisocial, terrible, untoward, questionable, perverted, reprehensible. And all the other suggestions and more. You'll want to look at a thesaurus.

Comment: It's really impossible to answer this question in a targeted manner unless you clarify what specific *type* of adjective you're looking for. Alternatives to what's already been suggested: *juvenile, unthinking, unclothed, untaught, strange, curious, uninherited* . . .

Comment: Why not just use the word "behaviour", all concerned seem to know what he did and the fact that you are apologising means that it was in some way (...insert the word your looking for...). Using more words (or worse the wrong word) does not add sophistication, especially if it is clear that the word is not part of your lexicon.

Comment: If you have to apologize for your son's behaviour, "making me look good" should not be a concern - your son's future should be. You want to make it sincere without using a word that has a very negative connotation that would be detrimental for your son. "inappropriate" is probably one of the better words from the ones mentioned. (Even if this is an exercise)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I'd recommend either "Distasteful" or "Indecent".

"Distasteful" conveys a sense that you are repelled by what your son did and that it is not what you have taught him, while "Indecent" conveys a sense that you have a very precise grasp of the situation (namely, it echoes the phrase "public indecency") and also acknowledge it as completely wrong and obscene.

Use "Distasteful" if you want to appeal to emotion (Pathos), but use "Indecent" if you want to create a sense of credibility (Ethos).

Answer (score 0):

a **faus pas**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/faux+pas)

> An embarrassing blunder or breach of proper etiquette, often made in
>   front of other people.

Answer (score 0):

“Unprecedented” might be useful if it’s an atypical behavior.
It might lead one to consider that there is no lingering issue; that it is a first-time and unexpected behavior, one which you will address accordingly.